# Open TikTok from Flutter app using an intent

Tags: flutter, android-intent, dart, mobile-development

I'm developing a Flutter app in which I need to open a video from my app on the TikTok app's upload page.
After checking if the app is installed, I'm not quite sure how the intent should be written. Is it even possible to achieve this?